# Interfacing GPIO pins between a uC and RS-485 tranceiver

Tags: current, resistance, gpio

uC: [EM357 datasheet](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/EM35x.pdf)
RS-485 IC: [sp3078e datasheet](http://www.exar.com/Files/Documents/SP3070-3078E_100_061109.pdf)

Two input pins on the sp3078e need to go high at the same time when I'm sending bytes.  I'm using a single output pin on the EM357 to drive both of them high and low.  The EM357 datasheet says the max output current for the pin that I'm using is 4 milli Amp.  The max input current on the sp3078e is 1 micro Amp.  Do these connections require any series resistance or pull-up/pull-down?

Answer (score 1):

Just tie the direction control pins together and drive them directly. I use 3073 with 3.3V GPIO and a TTL UART and it works great. If you are going a long distance - RS-485 on a twisted pair is good for a thousand meters or more - put a termination resistor at the far end. 220 Ohms is good (opinions vary on termination).

Comment: I thought the "standard" was 120 Ohms termination, that's what I've always seen anyway.

Comment: I don't know of any standard. A full termination in some data sheets uses three resistors with a 120 across A and B and a pair of 600 or 620 Ohm from A to V+ and B to ground. I have never used that configuration.